# Firefox and IE on Win7 not respecting Z-Index on YouTube iFrame

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, iframe, youtube-api, squarespace

Working on a simple squarespace website, normally adding a background video is straight forwards however the youtube video I've been instructed to use on this website no matter what I change on the parameters for the video or using z-index on the site display the content on top of the video in IE and FireFox yet Chrome works no problem. Link to site below...

https://kieran-miles-njfu.squarespace.com/

Help!

P.S. You will need to enter as a visitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youtube videos are Flash. Flash has seniority over the Z-order so it is "always" going to overlay.

I had the same issue once and solved it by using `wmode` attribute. Try adding `?wmode=opaque` to the URL or `&wmode=opaque` if there already is a parameter.

Comment: I tried this as follows:

<div style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; background-image:url(https://static.squarespace.com/static/546f5de7e4b0e2711c684c2c/t/5473675be4b02f4a4c8d0263/1416849248082/4.jpg?format=1500w&storage=local);">
<div style="position: absolute; top:-40%; left:-20%; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<iframe frameborder="0" height="150%" width="130%" style="position:absolute;" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/v/6UuzbOhC9Is?version=3&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=6UuzbOhC9Is&wmode=Opaque" wmode="Opaque">
</iframe>
</div>
</div>

But that didn't work, hmm...